# Are there ways to run a Lisp-in-box on the server?

Tags: ide, centos, common-lisp

The version I run on my desktop has Emacs, a common list compiler, and SLIME a lisp IDE.  This would be good for collaboration and testing of any functionality that includes internet protocols.

My server has CentOS and so the package manager is YUM I believe.
Thanks,
Bruce

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if you can run Lisp-in-box on a server, but you could run a
Lisp with SWANK on your server. Then, your collaborators and yourself
would be able to connect to it with
<kbd>M-x</kbd>`slime-connect`<kbd>RET</kbd>.

And if you want to use a secure connection, just make sure SWANK
listen only on localhost, then you can make an SSH tunnel.

```
ssh -f -N -L 4005:localhost:4005 $user@$host
```

Bonus:
This
[blogpost](http://directed-procrastination.blogspot.fr/2012/07/adventures-in-collaborative-coding-with.html)
is about collaborative coding with Common Lisp.